# Mac app icons dissapearing and reappearing randomly

Tags: finder, dock, icon, bug

Alright so most of the people have their desktop having some missing icons but i'm not really having this problem, the real problem is that all the apps in finder are missing icons and sometimes they reappear weirdly...

[image]

DolphinEMU's icon is the most inactive.

When i look up on finder... this happens...

[image]

Yes it's french, but almost all my apps have no icon and they reappear sometimes. they still run perfectly.